# Passing and calling dynamic blocks in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

As part of a unit test framework, I'm writing a function `genArray` that will generate NSArrays populated by a passed in generator block. So `[ObjCheck genArray: genInt]` would generate an NSArray of random integers, `[ObjCheck genArray: genChar]` would generate an NSArray of random characters, etc. In particular, I'm getting compiler errors in my implementation of `genArray` and `genString`, a wrapper around `[ObjCheck genArray: genChar]`.

I believe Objective C can manipulate blocks this dynamically, but I don't have the syntax right.

[ObjCheck.m](https://github.com/mcandre/objcheck/blob/master/ObjCheck.m)

```
+ (id) genArray: (id) gen {
    NSArray* arr = [NSMutableArray array];

    int len = [self genInt] % 100;

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        id value = gen();

        arr = [arr arrayByAddingObject: value];
    }

    return arr;
}

+ (id) genString {
    NSString* s = @"";

    char (^g)() = ^() {
        return [ObjCheck genChar];
    };

    NSArray* arr = [self genArray: g];
    s = [arr componentsJoinedByString: @""];

    return s;
}
```

When I try to compile, gcc complains that it can't do `gen()`, because `gen` is not a function. This makes sense, since `gen` is indeed not a function but an `id` which must be cast to a function.

But when I rewrite the signatures to use `id^()` instead of `id`, I also get compiler errors. Can Objective C handle arbitrarily typed blocks (genArray needs this), or is that too dynamic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that blocks are objects, you can cast between block types and `id` whenever you want, though if you cast the block to the wrong block type and call it, you're going to get unexpected results (since there's no way to dynamically check at runtime what the "real" type of the block is*).

BTW, `id^()` isn't a type. You're thinking of `id(^)()`. This may be a source of compiler error for you. You should be able to update `+genArray:` to use

```
id value = ((id(^)())(gen))();
```

Naturally, that's pretty ugly.

*There actually is a way, llvm inserts an obj-c type-encoded string representing the type of the block into the block's internal structure, but this is an implementation detail and would rely on you casting the block to its internal implementation structure in order to extract.

Comment: Thanks! Now that `genArray` works, I've got a different problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748616/how-do-you-join-an-nsarray-of-number-numberwithchar-cs-into-an-nsstring

Comment: @Kevin Ballard **  Kev..  how PRAY TELL  do you read the  "obj-c type-encoded string representing the type of the block" that "llvm inserts" "into the block's internal structure"?  you're my hero if you know the secret voodoo of decoding a bloack's type!

Comment: @alexgray: You can pull the struct definition from the [Clang documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Block-ABI-Apple.html). As for the type encoding itself, you can find it in the obj-c documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Blocks are a C-level feature, not an ObjC one - you work with them analogously to function pointers. There's [an article with a very concise overview of the syntax](http://thirdcog.eu/pwcblocks/#cblocks). (And most everything else.)

In your example, I'd make the `gen` parameter an `id (^gen)()`. (Or possibly make it return a `void*`, using `id` would imply to me that `gen` generates ObjC objects and not completely arbitrary types.)

Comment: If I understand the spec right, blocks are only guaranteed to be an Objective-C object in an Obj-C context, and I'm not sure what the benefit is besides consistency. It certainly doesn't seem to be the intent that they be used as ObjC objects much, none of the official documentation does.

Comment: Most importantly, there doesn't seem to be a way to *call* the block using an ObjC message, which is the OP's problem.

Answer (score 1):

No matter how you declare your variables and parameters, your code won't work. There's a problem that runs through all your compiler errors and it would be a problem even if you weren't doing convoluted things with blocks.

You are trying to add chars to an NSArray. You can't do that. You will have to wrap them them as some kind of Objective C object. Since your only requirement for this example to work is that the objects can be inputs to componentsJoinedByString, you can return single-character NSStrings from g. Then some variety of signature like id^() will work for genArray. I'm not sure how you parenthesize it. Something like this:

```
+ (id) genArray: (id^()) gen;

+ (id) genString {
    ...
    NSString * (^g)() = ^() {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [ObjCheck genChar]];
    };
    ...
}
```

NSString * is an id. char is not. You can pass NSString * ^() to id ^(), but you get a compiler error when you try to pass a char ^() to an id ^(). If you gave up some generality of genArray and declared it to accept char ^(), it would compile your call to genArray, but would have an error within genArray when you tried to call arrayByAddingObject and the argument isn't typed as an id.

Somebody who understands the intricacies of block syntax feel free to edit my post if I got some subtle syntax errors.

Btw, use an NSMutableArray as your local variable in genArray. Calling arrayByAddingObject over and over again will have O(n^2) time performance I imagine. You can still declare the return type as NSArray, which is a superclass of NSMutableArray, and the callers of genArray won't know the difference.

Comment: Are blocks themselves objects? The final piece to the unit test framework is a `forAll` function which would accept a property (block returning BOOL or [NSNumber numberWithBool: b]) and an NSArray of generator blocks.

Comment: I don't have the answer to that for you.