# How do you join an NSArray of [Number numberWithChar: c]'s into an NSString?

Tags: objective-c, join, nsstring, nsarray, char

When I use `componentsJoinedByString`, I just get a long string of digits.

Edit: I realize this task is confusing. Why on earth would anyone populate an NSArray with NSNumbers if they wanted an NSString? The answer is that I'm writing an extensible unit test framework. The basic functions `genNum`, `genBool`, and `genChar` generate NSNumbers with random int, BOOL, and char values respectively. Then there's `genArray` which generates a random array using a specified generator. So to construct a random NSString, one would run `genArray` using the `genChar` generator, and transform the resulting NSArray into an NSString.

The characters are only stored as `NSNumber`s instead of `char`s due to a technicality: `genArray` accepts a block and calls the block 100-odd times to populate the NSArray. Blocks must hold ObjC objects; not primitive types.

So the question remains: How do you join an NSArray of [NSNumber numberWithChar: c]'s into an NSString?

Comment: Post more of the NSArray elements and what you expect.

Comment: You may need to iterate over the array "by hand" and construct the string by examining each element, rather than trying to use something like `componentsJoinedByString:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
+ (NSString *) genString {
    NSArray* arr = [self genArray: ^() { return [ObjCheck genChar]; }];

    NSMutableString* s = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity: [arr count]];

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < [arr count]; i++) {
        [s appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%c", [[arr objectAtIndex: i] charValue]]];
    }

    return s;
}
```

Comment: This is a good start, but I have a few questions. First off, why are you pre-filling the array with NUL bytes? You're just going to overwrite every single one of those bytes. Secondly, you're not actually NUL-terminating, since you're only filling up to `[arr count]`. Thirdly, if you really do want to zero-fill, just use `calloc()` instead of `malloc()`. Fourthly, you're assuming that all the char's are <= 127. Any chars between 128 and 255 aren't going to be valid UTF-8 bytes. This last issue requires asking the OP what he wants - treat as unicode codepoints, or just pick an encoding?

Comment: In my experience, when allocating space for a cstring there is often random data there that manages to slip past NUL bytes, probably an artifact of how poorly I malloc() things. But your technical points are correct. /facepalm that I don't even put a NUL where it should go. As genChar automatically moduluses random integers over 128, none will be over 127 (see the code at GitHub).

Answer (score 2):

`componentsJoinedByString` joins the array elements into a string with the separator character between them.  The array elements are converted to strings (if not already `NSString`" using the `description` method.  If you have n array of `NSNumbers` I would expect an interesting result.

Answer (score 1):

Why not fill your array with `[NSString stringWithCharacters:c length:1]`? Then `componentsJoinedByString:` ought to work. (Check the docs on `stringWithCharacters:length:`; the above is just for illustration. You might have to use `&c`, for example.)

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (id)genString {
    NSArray *chars = [self genArray:^{ return [ObjCheck genChar]; }];

    if ([chars count] == 0) {
        return @"";
    }

    unichar *buffer = malloc(sizeof(unichar) * [chars count]);

    [chars enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSNumber *num, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        buffer[idx] = (unichar)[num charValue];
    }];

    return [[[NSString alloc] initWithCharactersNoCopy:buffer length:[chars count] freeWhenDone:YES] autorelease];
}
```

This particular solution will assume chars >127 should be treated as unicode codepoints (which basically means, for char-sized values, as ISO-8859-1). It also avoids copying the buffer when creating the resulting string.

Comment: Why use CFString over NSString?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to cast it. CFString is NSString. And really, I just couldn't be arsed to look up the right NSString equivalent. I'll edit it now to use the NSString method instead.

Comment: @mcandre: Ok, it's now using NSString. I also added the `-autorelease` that I had forgotten about. Guess that's what I get for writing code in a browser.